# What does `descendant` mean in XPATHNavigator's Compile function?

Tags: c++, xml, xpathnavigator

I've googled for few pages but failed to find the meaning of descendant word as typed out in the code below.

```
System::Xml::XPath::XPathExpression^ expr = nav->Compile("descendant::delivery[stockcode='ZMY201HR6US-A']");
```

Can someone tell me what `descendant` means?Thanks to anyone's helps.

Answer (score 0):

`descendant` means:

> Selects all descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.) of the current node

It comes from the XPath "axes" syntax.

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp

In your example, the qualifiers following it mean that the statement itself will select any `delivery` nodes with stockcode of ZMY201HR6US-A that are sub-nodes from the current node.